# combining transclude and directive inheritance in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have this html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>
```

and the following Angular code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('parent', function() {
return {
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getContent = function () {
            console.log('called getContent');
        }
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>parent <span ng-transclude></span></span>'
}
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:true,
    template: '<div>child</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getContent();
    }
}
});
```

JSfiddle of the above is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpwasrkz/1/)

my problem in this example is i can see the inheritance working and transclusion working in isolation but when i try to combine the two, the child directive has no knowledge of the parent scope and hence the function getContent. So no console.log and before that the child directive errors that scope.getContent is undefined.

I realise that this might be that the child directive is no longer a child having been transcluded so i was thinking i need to start playing with post and prelink functions in the compile method maybe? or do i need to define a custom transclude function in the parent?

Any pointers for the code or further reading appreciated - i have read and similar questions on here about this kind of thing but am finding it difficult to follow and hoping some one can solve my hello world to kickstart my understanding

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read that article: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/

Basically, your child link is called before the parent one. What you want to do is use your parent pre-link function so scope.getContent is defined beforte the child is linked.

```
link: {
    pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getContent = function () {
            console.log('called');
        }
    }
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/floribon/gpwasrkz/3/

Comment: ok nice, thanks. I didnt realise you could use the pre and postlink methods like that either, i thought you had to define them in the compile method

Comment: marked this a correct answer as it helps understanding of the order in which things happen in this scenario, which was my main suspicion of why this wasnt working for me - thanks floribon

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ["Creating Directives that Communicate"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) in the docs. Maybe this is a solution for what you are trying o achieve. You can require the parent controller and call it's functions:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.getContent = function () {
                console.log('called')
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {},
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span>parent <span ng-transclude></span></span>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        require: '^parent',
        template: '<div>child</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.getContent();
        }
    }
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9neeoyh/).

Comment: Thanks also for this alternative approach +1